# remove the spaces betwwen the tags in local xml file in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having an xml named test11.xml now when i  pasrse the data into CXML there are spaces in the parsed xml i want to remove these space ..
Kindly Find my  xml data as below 
thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve"><o:DocumentProperties></o:DocumentProperties><w:fonts><w:defaultFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:fareast="Times New Roman" w:h-ansi="Times New Roman" w:cs="Times New Roman"/></w:fonts><w:docPr></w:docPr><w:body><wx:sect><w:p><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="560" w:first-line="-560"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Menlo" w:h-ansi="Menlo" w:cs="Menlo"/><wx:font wx:val="Menlo"/><w:sz w:val="22"/><w:sz-cs w:val="22"/><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;CXMLDocument 0x5d16270 [0x5d1b0e0]&gt; &lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="560" w:first-line="-560"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Menlo" w:h-ansi="Menlo" w:cs="Menlo"/><wx:font wx:val="Menlo"/><w:sz w:val="22"/><w:sz-cs w:val="22"/><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;feed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many options i suggest is read the xml in a string then use the function of the string replaceOccuranceOfString to replace space with blank and then parse the data into cxml.

Happy coding...